# Java code to search for strings and other relating strings

Tags: java

In a text file I have the following Entries

```
1|002|3|Lubna|M|141021081331|

2|003|3|Rashid|1|141021081431|

3|002|3|Amal|M|141021081340|

4|002|3|Lubna|F|141021081531|
```

I want to create a Java code to check for the existence of `|M|`; i.e. means `Lubna` is searching for something. And to check after that if `Lubna` found what she was searching about, and that will happen if for the same username is followed by `|F|`.

for example :

```
1|002|3|Lubna|M|141021081331| ---> Lubna is searching
1|002|3|Lubna|F|141021081531| ---> Lubna found what she was searching about

1|002|3|Amal|M|141021081340|----> Amal is searching
```

But because there is no amal record include `|F|` so that mean she is still searching..
Provide the records might be unlimited , i.e. not only 4 as in the above example..
So what I did is the following:

```
String st;        
// where 14 is num of columns in record , like in our examle they are 6 
String [] subst= new String [14] ; 
while ((st = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
    if (st.contains("|M|")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            subst=st.split("[|]");  
        }
        System.out.println(subst);
        n++;
    }
    else
    if (st.contains("|F|")) {
        // System.out.println(EmailBody[j]);                    
    }
}
```

In this if I will manage to make this subst not only 1 dimension array of string, but make it 2, I can search for the existence of `|F|`, but the problem is that I can't initialize such this kind of arrays because I don't know what its second dimension will be..

Any one can help me if finding an easiest way to achieve my need ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try regular expressions. But be careful with huge amount of data. Could be slow.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SearchDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "1|002|3|Lubna|M|141021081331|\n"
                + "2|003|3|Rashid|1|141021081431|\n"
                + "3|002|3|Amal|M|141021081340|\n"
                + "4|002|3|Lubna|F|141021081531|";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+[|]([^|]+)[|]([M]?)[|]\\d+[|]", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("search name: " + m.group(1) + " type: " + m.group(2));
            Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^\\d+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+[|](" + m.group(1) + ")[|]([F]?)[|]\\d+[|]", Pattern.MULTILINE);
            Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(data);
            if (m2.find()) {
                System.out.println("found name: " + m2.group(1) + " type: " + m2.group(2));
            } else {
                System.out.println("no match name: " + m.group(1) + " type: " + m.group(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i think that what i am looking for.. i will try it and i will get back to you with my results..

Comment: how i can write the following :

Comment: Pattern p : 002|0000|00|00002392651|41932.3409953704|00032018|M|        |1|2|room 2|guest03 guest03|0|141020081102|

Comment: pattern p2: 002|0000|00|00000000000|41932.3459606481|00000000|F|00000000|1|2|OFFICE 2||0|141020081811|

Comment: how i can write them as what you did ?

Comment: P can be : ^\\d+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+[|]([M]?)[|]\\s++[|]+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+[|]\\w+[|]\\w+[|]\\d+[|]\\d+                                  ??????

Comment: Sorry, I am late. Can you update your original question with your new problem, please. It is much easier to read a formatted text. Maybe you can place a header above your data. Then I know which column you mean and last but not least - an example would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

`"the problem is that I can't initialize such this kind of arrays because I don't know what its second dimension will be.."`

You want to look into the [collections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm) framework which allows you to create lists without specifying size.

So:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you can add stufff to list:

```
list.add("stuff");
list.add("stuff2");
list.add("stuff3");
//as many time as you want
```

Loop

```
for(String str : list)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

And then rest of code.

For a tutorial on collections, checkout [caveOfProgramming](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/youtube/#10)

Comment: Iterating via index is usually not what you want to do. Use Iterators instead! for(String str : list)...

Comment: @haywire I agree and thanks for the edit. I just thought it'd be easier for OP to get his head round

Answer (score 0):

load like this, then iterate LinesList

```
    String filename = "myfile.txt";
    List<String> LinesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Path filePath = new File(filename).toPath();
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    try {
        LinesList = Files.readAllLines(filePath, charset);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof NoSuchFileException) {
            System.out.println("error: file not found!");
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(101);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i think reading the whole file line will solve some part of my issue, .. thank you so much again ..